# How to save a change after MouseClick and closing menu?

Tags: vb.net

I'm sorry if this is a very basic question, I couldn't find an answer through Google.

```
Private Sub Button2_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseClick
    If Label1.Text = "OFF" Then
        Label1.Text = "ON"
    Else
        Label1.Text = "OFF"
    End If

End Sub
```

How do I save the change of "ON" or "OFF", so that when I close with Me.Close() and open it again with Me.Show(), it is still there? And if I want to add colours or other stuff that also change, so that I could save them also. I want to also refer to those infos(the ON or OFF text) from other forms.

Edit:

I can't seem to find a way to save my settings, even though I have tried different ways. I have in my Settings page *Access Modifier: Public* and then one setting line: *Paalla, String, User, OFF* in the fields. When I close the form, and open it again from another form, the changes are gone.

```
Private Sub Button2_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseClick
    If My.Settings.Paalla = "OFF" Then
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Orange
        Label1.Text = "ON"
        My.Settings.Paalla = "ON"
        My.Settings.Save()
    Else
        Button2.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro
        Label1.Text = "OFF"
        My.Settings.Paalla = "OFF"
        My.Settings.Save()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: look into `My.Settings`

Comment: Another possible way is write all of your settings data to a file before form close. (into FormClosing event). Then when the form load again just change all settings using the saved file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the button, and in the properties window set the application setting (text property) to a new variable (because you are just using off and on, I set the example to be a boolean)

Then in the mouse click event event set the variable

*Label Text is the name of the application settings variable*

```
Private Sub Button2_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Button2.MouseClick
If Label1.Text = "OFF" Then
    Label1.Text = "ON"
    My.Settings.LabelText = True
    My.Settings.Save()
Else
    Label1.Text = "OFF"
    My.Settings.LabelText= False
    My.Settings.Save()
End If

End Sub
```

Then you need to load these settings when you load the button text

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
If My.Settings.LabelText = True then
    Label1.Text = "ON"
Else: Label1.Text="OFF"
End If
End Sub
```